# Уточнение или однородный член?

Tags: однородные-члены, уточнения

Как расценивать сочетание "вся её суть" в приведенном ниже предложении? Как уточнение или однородное подлежащее, соответственно, нужна ли вторая запятая? И если всё же однородное, корректно ли употребление сказуемого в единственном числе?

*Да вся жизнь наша, вся её суть (?) неразрывно связана с этими хвойными брусочками толщиной шестьдесят на сорок миллиметров и длиной три метра.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Да вся жИзнь наша, вся её сУть** / неразрывно связана с этими хвойными брусочками толщиной шестьдесят на сорок миллиметров и длиной три метра.*

1. Думаю, что уточнения здесь **нет**, в том числе нет интонационного выделения (интонация перечислительная).

Это фактически **повтор**, риторический прием: *вся жизнь, вся суть жизни.*

Можно понять так: *Да вся жизнь наша по сути / неразрывно связана...*

2. При уточнении мы **подчеркиваем/выделяем** "вся суть жизни", но надо ли это делать? В общем случае все зависит от контекста, но можно предположить, что необходимости в этом нет.

Comment: Спасибо! Как всегда, исчерпывающий ответ. Тоже склонялась к повтору, но не знала, как оппоненту объяснить. Вы меня выручили )).